# When is it appropriate to use continue in Java?

Tags: java, loops, continue

I am currently learning java in class, and switching from python (which I'm also not that familiar with), it seems like nobody really likes using continues in their work, and the teacher told me it's just not something that's necessary.

For cases like this, where I'm trying to get a file name that doesn't exist as an input from the user, I get that I could put break in the else portion of if/else, but using continue just seems cleaner to me.

```
while(true)
    {
        File output = new File(input.next());
        if(output.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("That file already exists! Please enter another name.");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Is there any reason why I shouldn't use continues rather than else?

EDIT: never mind, this code is dumb and is way more complicated than necessary. Turns out, it's just easier to not mess with continues. Changed to:

```
File output = new File(input.next());
    while(output.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("That file already exists!");
        output = new File(input.next());
    }
```

I think this is much simpler and works. Sorry about the dumb question.

Comment: To skip over other future if-statements and other lines of code?

Comment: I would write that as `if (!output.exists()) { break; } System.out.println(...);`. No need for both `continue` and `break`.

Comment: it might not be necessary, but that doesn't mean it's not sometimes useful in writing code that is easy to understand. Computers understand binary, so why don't we just write code with ones and zeroes? every other character is unnecessary, right? 01101110 01101111 01110000 01100101

Comment: Answer: when it gives the best result WRT readability.  This must  be judged on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: "it seems like nobody really likes using continues in their work" .. is certainly not true.  "the teacher told me it's just not something that's necessary." ... it is not necessary in this case.  Any Java code that uses `continue` *could* be rewritten / restructured to not use it.  Whether doing that is a good idea in all cases is highly debatable.  See my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks guys, you've been pretty helpful in just a few minutes. I'll keep note of what you've said when writing code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of personal preference.  I use both `continue` and `break` depending on how I think about what I am doing.

The same argument could be applied to `boolean` values.

```java
boolean running = true;
while (running) {
   // do something.
}
```

or

```java
boolean idle = false;
while (!idle) {
   // do something
}
```

And don't forget you can use continue and break with labels.  These are especially handy for controlling nested loops.

And there have been times when I could have used a `do/until` construct just because it made the code seem clearer.